# jsTree load children by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

Code posted below loads root elements for my tree by ajax request. 
My tree is very large so I can't load  all items at once so I need to load elements by requesting children for specific ID's.

How do I load elements by ajax by clicking on node?

```
  $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({
            "plugins" : ["wholerow", "checkbox"],
            'core' : {
                'data' : {
                    'url' : function(node) {
                        return "/" + site + "/places/api/tree/list/";
                    }
                },
            }

        });
```

Part of json sample

```
[
   {
      "text":"zachodniopomorskie",
      "state":"closed",
      "id":212353,
   },
```

Fixed version:

```
 $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({
            "plugins" : ["wholerow", "checkbox"],
            'core' : {
                'data' : {
                    'url' : "/" + site + "/places/api/tree/list/",
                    'data' : function(node) {
                        return {
                            'id' : node.id
                        };
                    }
                },
            }
        })
```

The solution to my problem is that if I want to return children by ajax request I need to return json file which contains:

```
"children:" true
```

Comment: +1 for `"children":true`. jstree is awesome but docu sucks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({
            "plugins" : ["wholerow", "checkbox"],
            'core' : {
                'data' : {
                    'url' : "/" + site + "/places/api/tree/list/",
                    'data' : function(node) {
                        return {
                            'id' : node.id
                        };
                    }
                },
            }
        })
```

The solution to my problem is that if I want to return children by ajax request I need to return json file which contains:

```
"children:" true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('#jstree_demo_div').jstree(options).bind("select_node.jstree",function(event, data){
//Load child node here 

});//or "dbclick.jstree" instead of "select_node.jstree"
```

Comment: I still don't understand how the child node should be loaded. 

What function I should call there?

Comment: I got it fixed. Check my solution

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load child node you may try using

```
$("#jstree_demo_div").bind("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
    $("#jstree_demo_div").jstree('open_node', data.node);
}
```

so it would fire an ajax load trigger.

Comment: Check my answer in the 1st post