# How to populate data on click on jstree last node via ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i want to make `jstree` as shown below

[image]

i want to get last node data with `ajax` call  which is `File 1` and `File 2`

**Note:**   i'm **hardcoding** last node data below to simulate `ajax` call

**Jsfiddle:**  https://jsfiddle.net/vym16okw/11/

```
 var s = [];
            s.push(
                { "id" : "ajson5", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "File 1", "date":"12", },
                { "id" : "ajson6", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "File 2", "date":"12" }
            );
```

**here is what i have tried:**

```js
$('#using_json_2').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : [
       { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Simple root node", "date":"2018"},
       { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2", "date":"2018"},
       { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1", "date":"12" },
       { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2", "date":"12" },
    ]
} });

   $('#using_json_2').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data){
      console.log("node_id: " , data,'original',data.node.original);  
      var id = data.node.original.id;
      var date = data.node.original.date;
      $.ajax({
          url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+id+'?date='+date,
          type:'GET',
          success:function(data){
            var s = [];
            s.push(
                { "id" : "ajson5", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "File 1", "date":"12","children": true },
                { "id" : "ajson6", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "File 2", "date":"12","children": true }
            );
          }
      });
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>


<div id="using_json_2"></div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!!!!!!!

Comment: this might help, https://stackoverflow.com/a/32853755/2630817

Comment: @Justcode, the aboe link is very similar to my problem, having `site` as dynamic `variable` like mine `id`. BUT i don't know how to implement it? if any help i would be glad

Comment: The link contains an implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's required:

```
"check_callback": true,
```

while creating the jstree at core level.

From [doc](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.core.check_callback):

> determines what happens when a user tries to modify the structure of the tree
>
> If left as false all operations like create, rename, delete, move or copy are prevented.
>
> You can set this to true to allow all interactions or use a function to have better control.

For each newly node you don't need the parent attribute:

```
{ "id" : "ajson5", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "File 1", "date":"12","children": true }
```

because it is the first parameter for create_node:

```
$('#using_json_2').jstree().create_node(lastNode,  ele, "last");
```

```js
$('#using_json_2').jstree({
    'core': {
        "check_callback": true,
        "data": [
            {"id": "ajson1", "parent": "#", "text": "Simple root node", "date": "2018"},
            {"id": "ajson2", "parent": "#", "text": "Root node 2", "date": "2018"},
            {"id": "ajson3", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 1", "date": "12"},
            {"id": "ajson4", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 2", "date": "12"},
        ]
    }
});
$('#using_json_2').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    // get last node....
    var model = $(this).jstree(true)._model.data;
    var result = [];
    for (var i in model) {
        if (model.hasOwnProperty(i) && !model[i].children.length) {
            result.push(i);
        }
    }
    // ...the last node
    var lastNode = result.pop();
    var id = data.node.original.id;
    // if current node is not the last....
    if (id != lastNode) {
        return;
    }
    // set loading ....
    $('#' + lastNode).addClass("jstree-loading").attr('aria-busy',true);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            var s = [];
            s.push(
                    {
                        "id": "ajson5",
                        "text": "File 1",
                        "date": "12",
                        "children": false,
                        "icon": "jstree-file"
                    }, {
                        "id": "ajson6",
                        "text": "File 2",
                        "date": "12",
                        "children": false,
                        "icon": "jstree-file"
                    }
            );
            s.forEach(function (ele) {
                $('#using_json_2').jstree().create_node(lastNode, ele, "last");
            });
            // open node
            $('#using_json_2').jstree().open_node(lastNode);
            // unset loading ....
            $('#' + lastNode).removeClass("jstree-loading").attr('aria-busy',false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>


<div id="using_json_2"></div>
```

Comment: Really Great Answer, but 2 things is missing, **1.** file type icon(i don't want to show last children i,e `File 1 & File 2` as **folder** but as file ).  **2.** loading icon when last node is clicked.  **if possible please help me otherwise i'm happy with the above solution**

Comment: **i have solved first (1) problem** by setting by `"icon":"fa fa-file-o"` into this `object`  `{ "id" : "ajson5", "text" : "File 1", "date":"12","children": false,"icon":"fa fa-file-o" },
                    { "id" : "ajson6", "text" : "File 2", "date":"12","children": false,"icon":"fa fa-file-o" }` of `s`. **(2) Problem:** i'm still looking for solution please help me

Comment: @skBangalore Snippet updated. Now you can see how to set/unset loading icon plus the standard file type icon belonging to jstree.